# Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Eclipse Modeling Tools and Papyrus

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

I have Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Helios) installed. I want to add an UML plugin, Papyrus, to it. I tried online install and local install the Papyrus. But none works for me. By looking at Papyrus tutorial carefully,[tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/usersTutorials/resources/TutorialOnPapyrusUSE_d20101001.pdf), I found it referes to the Eclipse Modeling Tools. Is that mean I have to install the Eclipse Modeling Tools? Then I have to use two separate tools from Eclipse?

EDIT:

**Found the answer:**

The link to update the Papyrus for Helios is this: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/releases/helios

The latest source download from papyrus site is for indigo, I think.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Papyrus is not a plugin. You need to download the full Papyrus packages which is bundle of Eclipse Helios and UML plugins. If you use Java then it is not possible to install Papyrus because this modeling tool is not related to java.

Papyrus is working well but requires it own modeling environment as opposed to java. This is fully logical because modeling is not always related to Java but more MDA.

Comment: Papyrus is an Eclipse plugin.